# awk, custom delarray function

Tags: arrays, function, awk

Can someone explain, why I am not getting expected results?

```
awk '
# I know there is delete array, but this is more portable
# that is what docs are saying, anyway wanted to test it out.
function delarray(a,  i)
{
    for (i in a)
        delete a[i]
}

BEGIN {
    a[3]=""
    a[4]=""
    for (e in a)
        print e
    delarray(a)
    for (e in a)
        print ".."
        print e
}
'
```

Executing the above script, I expected to see:

```
3
4
..(nothing here)
```

I used `..` thinking I won't see anything else because of
deleted array values so just to see `..` as placeholder)

,but the actual output I see is:

```
3
4
4 #(why this?, and where are two dots?)
```

,also exit code was 1, why is that?

Comment: Whatever docs you are reading that say creating that function is the alternative to `delete array`, throw them away. `split("",array)` is the portable alternative to `delete array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delete function worked.

Since you're missing the braces around your `for (e in a)` loop, it only contains the `print ".."` statement, which is why you don't see any dots.

The `print e` command simply prints the last value that was assigned to `e` (from the previous `for (e in a)` loop), which is `4`.

But your function is not very useful since virtually all versions of `awk` allow the `delete a` command without an index. It's in the POSIX standard.

Comment: But how that `e` from second `print e` survives after `delarray(a)` being called previously?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? It's not part of the array. It's a completely separate variable.

Comment: Oh yes indeed. Funny.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing curly braces around your second loop.

```
for (e in a) {
    print ".."
    print e
}
```

Output:

```
3
4
```